# How do I scroll to the last item in a Flickable's Repeater

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a [Flickable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html) that is holding two [Repeaters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html) with a column layout.  I am hoping to scroll to the last item in the first repeater.  Is this possible?

I suppose one way could be to count how many items are in the first repeater and then multiply that by the height of the delegate I am using. (The delegate is a fixed height.)  Or take the height of the repeater and subtract the height of the last delegate. etc...  Though I am hoping on a better way than this.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Item {
    id:passwordsView
    Flickable {
        id: flickable1
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight: passwordsView_column.height
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { }
        Column {
            id:passwordsView_column
            spacing: 15
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            Repeater {
                id: passwordsView_breadcrumb
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                model: BreadcrumbModel {}
                delegate: PasswordFolderDelegate {
                    y: 8;
                    anchors.left: parent.left;
                    anchors.right: parent.right;
                }
            }

            Repeater {
                id: passwordsView_contents
                model: PasswordModel {}
                PasswordFolderDelegate {
                    y: 8
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                }
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or take the height of the repeater and subtract the height of the last delegate.

`Repeater` doesn't have a height, as it merely positions the items, so that might be a little difficult.

The easiest approach I can think of is to use [`mapToItem()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToItem-method):

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Flickable {
        id: flickable1
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight: passwordsView_column.height
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { }
        Column {
            id:passwordsView_column
            spacing: 15
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            Repeater {
                id: passwordsView_breadcrumb
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                model: 10
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    width: 50
                    height: 50
                    color: "transparent"
                    border.color: "salmon"

                    Text {
                        text: index
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }
            }

            Repeater {
                id: passwordsView_contents
                model: 10
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    width: 50
                    height: 50
                    color: "transparent"
                    border.color: "#444"

                    Text {
                        text: index
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        text: "Position at end"
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.right: parent.right
        onClicked: {
            var lastItem = passwordsView_breadcrumb.itemAt(passwordsView_breadcrumb.count - 1);
            flickable1.contentY = lastItem.mapToItem(flickable1.contentItem, 0, 0).y
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this makes the view move instantly. If you want smooth scrolling, you'll probably have to calculate the required velocity somehow and pass it to [`flick()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#flick-method).

Comment: In your example, if I have a freshly loaded application and press the button it works.  However if I scroll down or change the position, it moves to the top first, and clicking again will move it to the last item. The hope was that the view would make it so that no matter the location it would always navigate to the last item on the event (in this case button onClick())

Comment: Ah, it should have been `flickable1.contentY = lastItem.mapToItem(flickable1.contentItem, 0, 0).y`.